# html and css: aligning a select to the right edge of a table

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML snippet. The desired effect is to have a dropdown be positioned right above a table.

```
<!-- this is actually in a proper CSS class, not inline-->
<div style="float:left; 
            min-height:1px;
            padding:15px 2% 20px;
            position:relative;
            width:96%;"> 

<form method="post">
<div style="float:right;display:inline;">Show Me:
    <select id="ddNumRecords" name="ddNumRecords" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option>30</option>
      <option>50</option>
      <option>100</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The above renders like this:

[table and select float right http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1253124526051538700.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1253124526051538700.png)

**Question:** How can I write my CSS to achieve positioning like this mockup?

[desired http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1253124791005327900.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1253124791005327900.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to your table's CSS. This will clear the float of the div (with the dropdown) above it.

But why don't you just `text-align: right;` your div, then you don't have to mess with floats and inline divs. That should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add absolute positioning to both divs.

or

Other way would be to use table. For example:

```
 <table>
    <tr><td>
    <form method="post">
    <div style="float:right;display:inline;">Show Me:
        <select id="ddNumRecords" name="ddNumRecords" onchange="this.form.submit();">
          <option>30</option>
          <option>50</option>
          <option>100</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </form>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <div>
    <div style="float:left; 
                min-height:1px;
                padding:15px 2% 20px;
                position:relative;
                width:96%;"> 
    hello world
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
```

or

Add one more div around the div that has float:right. For example:

```
<form method="post">
<div style="float:left; width:300px">
<div style="float:right;display:inline;">Show Me:
    <select id="ddNumRecords" name="ddNumRecords" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option>30</option>
      <option>50</option>
      <option>100</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div style="float:left; 
            min-height:1px;
            padding:15px 2% 20px;
            position:relative;
            width:96%;"> 
hello world
</div>
```

Comment: Always avoid absolute positioned divs whenever possible. Absolute positioned elements do not participate in the normal layout flow, so it makes it very hard to keep a structure in the page.

Comment: You are right. It is very difficult to maintain a page that has a lots of absolute positioning. When you want to put everything to 5 px right, u will have to change style of all controls manually to 5px right. I had experience this in the past. But it would resolve the problem that pcampbell had stated, i think.

Answer (score 0):

you could make another cell for the table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div style="float:right;display:inline;">Show Me:
    <select id="ddNumRecords" name="ddNumRecords" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option>30</option>
      <option>50</option>
      <option>100</option>
    </select>
</div>
</td
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table head</td>
<td>table head</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>content1</td>
<td>ontent2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>content3</td>
<td>content4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this should work.. or you could use css. but this is the fastest way to do it:-? at least until you make/find some css. you could use float left on both divs